# Iterating for loop multiple times then adding

Tags: python, loops

I'm writing a for loop-based program. I have a lucky number that is based on a random import. When the lucky numbers were added equal to an even number, I wanted to reroll the numbers 7 times, print them 1 by 1, and add them all up at the end. I've been trying but I get confused at using the for loop. Thanks for the help in advance

```py
import random

lucky_1: random.randint(1,56)
lucky_2 : random.randint(1, 56)

while (lucky_1 + lucky_2 % 2) == 0:
    print("You're even!")
    for (lucky_1) in range (1, 7):
        print (lucky_1)
        choice = input("Would you like to see your numbers:")
        if choice == 'yes':
            print (lucky_1 + lucky_1)
```

Comment: `lucky_1 + lucky_2 % 2` groups as `lucky_1 + (lucky_2 % 2)`, which clearly isn't what you want.  Add parentheses.

Comment: `lucky_1: random.randint(1,56)` is a type hint, not a variable declaration. I suspect you want `lucky_1 = random.randint(1,56)`, and the same for `lucky_2`. By itself, this will not solve your entire problem, but you need to address it before you can progress.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I can understand your question correctly. But, try something like this:

```
import random

lucky_1 = random.randint(1,56)
lucky_2 = random.randint(1, 56)

def lucky(lucky_1, lucky_2):
    numbers = []

    if (lucky_1 + lucky_2) % 2 == 0:
        print("You're Even!\nRe-rolling the numbers...\n\n")
        for i in range(1, 8):
            lucky_1 = random.randint(1, 56)
            lucky_2 = random.randint(1, 56)
            numbers.append(lucky_1+lucky_2)

            print(f'Roll: {i}')
            print(f'Your lucky number 1 -> {lucky_1}')
            print(f'Your lucky number 2 -> {lucky_2}\n')

    choice = input("Would you like to see your numbers: ")
    if choice == 'yes':
        print(f'\n=====================================\nYour final lucky numbers are {lucky_1} and {lucky_2}')
        print(f'Sum of numbers from seven rolls = {sum(numbers)}\n=====================================')
    else:
        print('Thank you.')

lucky(lucky_1, lucky_1)
```

**Result**:

```
You're Even!
Re-rolling the numbers...


Roll: 1
Your lucky number 1 -> 52
Your lucky number 2 -> 23

Roll: 2
Your lucky number 1 -> 4
Your lucky number 2 -> 43

Roll: 3
Your lucky number 1 -> 29
Your lucky number 2 -> 23

Roll: 4
Your lucky number 1 -> 47
Your lucky number 2 -> 11

Roll: 5
Your lucky number 1 -> 24
Your lucky number 2 -> 50

Roll: 6
Your lucky number 1 -> 17
Your lucky number 2 -> 31

Roll: 7
Your lucky number 1 -> 51
Your lucky number 2 -> 1

Would you like to see your numbers: yes

=====================================
Your final lucky numbers are 51 and 1
Sum of numbers from seven rolls = 406
=====================================
```